# how to accept both lower and upper case in jcombo box auto suggestion using jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtextfield

I created a class comboauto for to get an itemnames from mysql database in combo box. I did an auto suggestion in jcombobox assigned jtextfield as default, to get text in jtextfield. when i am typing a text U(it should auto suggest and give both lowercase and uppercase u values) in jcombobox. I am not getting both the case value when typing into a text. Please help me, what method i am supposed to use here.

```
This is the code i used
public class comboauto extends javax.swing.JFrame{
             Vector Tmpv1=new Vector();
             Statement TmpSqlStmnt;
             ResultSet TmpSqlRs;
             Connection Tmpcon;
             String TmpCateId;
             JTextField Txt01;
             TreeMap TmpMap=new TreeMap();

        public comboauto() {
               initComponents();
        }

        public void FRM_CBX_AUTOSUGGEST() {
               Txt01=(JTextField)Cbx01.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
                Txt01.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
               public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
                {
                       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                     {
                           public void run(){
                                  String Tmptext =Txt01.getText();
                                  if(Tmptext.length()==0)
                                   {
                                        Cbx01.hidePopup();
                                        setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(Tmpv1), "");
                                     }
                                     else{
                                       DefaultComboBoxModel m = getSuggestedModel(Tmpv1, Tmptext);
                                       if(m.getSize()==0 ) {
                                       Cbx01.hidePopup();
                                         }
                                        else{
                                                  setModel(m, Tmptext);
                                                 Cbx01.showPopup();

                                             }
                                         }
                                 }
                             });
                   }                        
            });
             try{
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Tmpcon =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","root");
                    TmpSqlStmnt=Tmpcon.createStatement();
                    TmpSqlRs=TmpSqlStmnt.executeQuery ("SELECT CateId,CateName FROM Cust_Masterrecord ORDER BY CateName");
                    System.out.println("DB Connected");
                    TmpSqlRs.first();
                    do {
                            String TmpName=TmpSqlRs.getString("CateName");
                            Cbx01.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                            Cbx01.addItem(TmpName);
                            int TmpCateId=TmpSqlRs.getInt("CateId");
                            Tmpv1.addElement(TmpSqlRs.getString("CateName"));
                            TmpMap.put(TmpName, TmpCateId);

                           Cbx01.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
                            {
                            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                                   if (e.getStateChange() == e.SELECTED) {

                                       Lbl01.setText(TmpMap.get(Cbx01.getSelectedItem()).toString());
                                  }
                                }
                            });
                    }while(TmpSqlRs.next());
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
  }
  }
private boolean hide_flag = false;
       private void setModel(DefaultComboBoxModel mdl, String str)
       {
        Cbx01.setModel(mdl);
        Cbx01.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        Txt01.setText(str);
       }
private static DefaultComboBoxModel getSuggestedModel(java.util.List<String> list, String text) {
        DefaultComboBoxModel m = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

        for(String s: list) {
            if(s.startsWith(text)) m.addElement(s);
        }
        return m;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               comboauto Tmpobj1= new comboauto();
               Tmpobj1.FRM_CBX_AUTOSUGGEST();
               Tmpobj1.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox Cbx01;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Lbl01;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the KeyListener has been triggered?@javasi

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them - _now_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String.toUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) in you getSuggestedModel method. (Uppercase both strings. Lowercase also works.)

Comment: It's working finely. I used String.toUpperCase() in two places, first where i am getting a resultset string value, second where i am getting text. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could compare using

> boolean   equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString) 
>            - Compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations.

Comment: After second thoughts, this is not good. You can't compare the whole strings.

Comment: True, but you answer does not imply this.